# Uploaded image blocked by client Magento 2

Tags: magento2, image-upload, file-permissions

i created an extension to upload image, the way i save the image is like this:

```
$uploader = $this->_uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);

$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);


$imageAdapter = $this->_adapterFactory->create();

$uploader->addValidateCallback('banner_image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);

$mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
$result = $uploader->save(
$mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath(\Test\Bannermanager\Model\Banner::BASE_MEDIA_PATH)
                    );
$data['image'] = \Test\Bannermanager\Model\Banner::BASE_MEDIA_PATH.$result['file'];
```

the file was save successfully, but when i want to display it, the html img tag always add `display:none !important;` and in browser console i always got this error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`, but when i opened the image url, it shows the image, and when i downloaded it failed and the browser says it blocked

[image: style]

[image: console]